# Select up to five items

Tags: python

How would I do a Random choice, but up to five instead of exactly five:

```
random.Random().sample(items[:40], 5) # select up to five random cues
```

For example, if there are only 2 items, it should only pick two. As it is now, it will raise a `ValueError` if there are less than five items.

Comment: If there are only two items, and you want to pick two items, it's not random.

Comment: @Oz123: the order will still be random, so it's not totally useless.  :)

Comment: @Oz123 -- in that case, it would just be randomly ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
random.Random().sample(items[:40], min(5, len(items[:40])))
```